# finding indicies of a list if they are outside a certain value. python, numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading in an array from the text file and want to eliminate data under a certain value but I also want to know their positions in the array of the deleted values, so I can use this to delete other data. My code bellow will remove the data if it is bellow a value but how can I find the indicies of the data that has been removed?

```
    y=np.genfromtxt('01_temp.txt').T[0]
    b=np.std(y)
    c=np.mean(y)
    low=c-b
    high=c+b
    x=[i for i in y if i>low]
    print x
```

I think the bellow code also does the same as above

```
y=np.genfromtxt('01_temp.txt').T[0]
b=np.std(y)
c=np.mean(y)
low=c-b
high=c+b
ok=y>low
y[ok]=low
```

How can I find the indices of the values out of the range I have set?

For example if my list is [5, 5, 8, 9, 0, 10, 3] and low=4 I want to return the indices bellow 4 which for this case would be [4,6]

Comment: It seems this is only a single dimension array why can't you do something like this: x=[(i,j) for i,j in enumerate(y) if i>low]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `y > low` what gets returned is a boolean array, of the same size as `y`, with `True` where the condition is met, and `False` where it is not. To get the indices of the `True`s you can use `np.where` or `np.nonzero`:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(10, size=(10,))
>>> a
array([3, 7, 5, 9, 3, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0])
>>> a > 3
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> np.where(a > 3)
(array([1, 2, 3, 5, 7], dtype=int64),)
>>> np.nonzero(a > 3)
(array([1, 2, 3, 5, 7], dtype=int64),)
```

Note that what gets returned is a tuple of arrays, so for the 1D case you will probably end up doing something like `indices = np.where(y > low)[0]`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't something like this work for you:

```
>>> y = [3,4,5,3,2,4,6,3]
>>> low = 3
>>> x=[(i,j) for i,j in enumerate(y) if i>low]
>>> x
[(4, 2), (5, 4), (6, 6), (7, 3)]
>>> x=[(i,j) for i,j in enumerate(y) if i<low]
>>> x
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)]
```